# Unrecognized options "service_name" under "service_name" - Symfony2 configuration builder

Tags: testing, symfony, bundle

I am trying to test configuration builder in my bundle:

This is my DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

```php
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * Generates the configuration tree.
     *
     * @return TreeBuilder
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('product_viewer');

        $supportedDrivers = array('REST', 'SOAP');

        $rootNode->children()
            ->arrayNode('car')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('webservice_type')
                        ->validate()
                            ->ifNotInArray($supportedDrivers)
                            ->thenInvalid('The driver %s is not supported. Please choose one of '.json_encode($supportedDrivers))
                        ->end()                
                    ->end()                
                    ->scalarNode('rest_url')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();                

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

my test:

```php
 /**
  * @test
  */
public function fullCondig() {
    $extension = new ProductCalculatorExtension();
    $config = $this->loadConfig('config1'); //this method only load yaml from file and parse it 
    $extension->load(array($config), new ContainerBuilder());
}
```

and tested config looks like:

```yaml
product_viewer:
    car : 
        webservice_type : REST
        rest_url: 'example.com'
```

unfortunately every test I got:

> Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException:
>   Unrecognized options "product_viewer" under  "product_viewer"

I am out of idea what could be wrong here?